# getting error in setting the folder permission

Tags: vb.net, directory

using vb.net set denied access to a particular folder.here i attached my code . but am getting error in my code like covert from string to type long is not valid

```
code
-----
           Dim ds1 As New TdeskTableAdapters.proc_checkuserrightsTableAdapter
            Dim dt1 As Tdesk.proc_checkuserrightsDataTable = ds1.GetData(ecode)

            For Each r1 As DataRow In dt1.Rows
                reqrights = r1("fld_reqrights").ToString
                approv_rights = r1("fld_approval").ToString
            Next

            If approv_rights = "n" Or approv_rights = "N" Then


                Dim FolderPath As String = "D:\Account\HA\" 'Specify the folder here

                Dim UserAccount As String = mailid \ pwd

                Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
                Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
                FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Deny))
                'FolderAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection(True, False) 'uncomment to remove existing permissions
                FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)

            End If


 getting error in this line 

 Dim UserAccount As String = mailid \ pwd error mentioned in the above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So etiher `mailid` or `pwd` is a `Long` and the other is a `String`.

I assume that `mailid` is a `Long`:

```
Dim UserAccount As String = mailid.ToString() & "\" & pwd
```

But if you use `&` to concatenate strings you can also omit the `ToString`.

Another readable way is using `String.Format` which also converts implicitely to string:

```
Dim UserAccount As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}", mailid, pwd)
```

Comment: the line "FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Deny))" shows an error

Comment: error:   Some or all identity references could not be translated

Comment: I have never used `FileSystemAccessRule` before. So maybe someone else wants to solve the next problem. But you might want to edit your question then to show it (or ask a different question).